# Why app linking is not working in Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-links

Everything in the app linking setup seems good. But still, the verification is failing.

I did the following checklist

1. assetlinks.json is correct and it hosted without any redirection (301 and 302).
2. The website has a valid SSL certificate issued by [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/legal-repository/)
3. Tested the statement list in [statement list tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and it looks good.
4. link configuration in Android manifest is correct. (I have two other domain support, verification of those links are successful)

Attaching the system verification log (the listed domains and package is not original)

```
2020-07-21 21:07:46.791 2423-5863/com.google.android.gms I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:0 scheme:"https" hosts:"mycompany.branch.app mycompany.branch.link universal.mycompany.com" package:"com.app.mycompany".
2020-07-21 21:07:49.263 2423-5863/com.google.android.gms I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 0 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:universal.mycompany.com.
```

Anything else needs to be checked? please share your thoughts. Is there any way to get the domaing verification failure reason?

**Edit**
There is some problem with the assetlink.json file hosting
I have checked it with https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://universal.mycompany.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

its returning timeout failure:

```
{
 "maxAge": "599.999999813s",
 "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: 
deadline_exceeded: Timeout occurred while fetching Web statements from 
https://universal.mycompany.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is 
equivalent to 'https://universal.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') 
 using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES 
 *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your 
query\n"
}
```

**Edit2:** The digital asset link is started returning statements correctly now, but still, the verification is failing for that one host.

adding response header keys:

[image]

Comment: Add the manifest entry of `<intent-filter>` and the actual link with question

Comment: I have this issue too, sometimes is working fine, sometimes has a timeout issue, how to fixed this issue? I have tested on 3 server, only 1 server got this issue.